# How repair npm run build in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

Hello I started work with javascript, nodejs, babel and webpack. When I use npm run build I have some error. I use Windows 10.

I try install depedencies again and again. I looking information amout 'rm' and gulp.

A fragment with build of webpack looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfBsL.jpg

In this picture is error of using rm -rf build
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWUNE.jpg
And when I remove this line I got problem with gulp:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rR3a.jpg

Without it I can't iport files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're just started, throw away what you have, get https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app (follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app), they're rather straightforward) and take it from there. It was specifically made to "just work(tm)" if you're starting with react, babel, webpack, etc.so you can focus on writing your app rather than debugging your build system.

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as images

Comment: I don't work in ReactJS it's clear javascript